# Installing Propritary Broadcom Wireless Drivers

Tags: wireless, broadcom

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm brand new to Linux and have no idea what I'm doing. I am trying to install these wifi drivers, https://github.com/antoineco/broadcom-wl. Could someone tell be how to install and activate them?

Comment: Please notice that the files were last changed 7 years ago; that means they are unlikely to build successfully on any modern not-end-of-life kernel version. Please follow the instructions at the duplicate. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Open `Software & Settings` and head on to the tab "Additional Drivers". Does it list any WiFi driver?

Comment: It does not @Archisman Panigrahi

Comment: Anyway, if the top answers in the other question do not help you, feel free to let us know, we will reopen this question.